# How to define the path to an image file in an Excel template

Tags: excel, vb.net, path

I have an Excel 2016 macro that places a picture located in a sub-folder of the folder the workbook is located in. It uses this code to select the specific file name located in the sub-folder \images:

```
imageFilename = "Double_Full_Float_Horizontal" ' Insert the filename of the image file to use (without extension)
                                               ' Code will use the file with that name in the image subfolder folder
                                               ' The extension is assumed to be png
                                               ' For a different extension, modify the code or change it so that you write the name with the extensinon
Set pic_one = .Pictures.Insert(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\images\" & imageFilename & ".png")
```

This works fine when the macro is run in the workbook but I need to convert the workbook to an xltm template.  When I do and I open a new workbook from the template the macro fails at this point with the error:

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Insert property of the Picture class

This is even though the images folder is a sub-folder of where the template is stored. I assume I might be able to get around this by somehow defining an absolute path to where the image folder is located but this would present problems as I cannot guarantee this location would remain fixed.  Would appreciate any tips on how to resolve.

Comment: You seem to think that the problem is accessing the file, but the error message says the problem is that the `Picture` class does not have an `Insert` property. It would help if could show the `With` statement so that we can be sure what `Pictures` is supposed to be.

Comment: Is the file you opened from the template saved before you run the macro?

Comment: Hi.  Fixed by saving the generated workbook before running the macro.  Thanks for the pointer.